# How to let android device "speak" Chinese?

Tags: android, localization, text-to-speech, cjk

I'm learning to develop app on Android with eclipse and ADT plug-in.

Now I want my app to read Chinese text, according to this artical in android SDK document http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/resources/articles/tts.html

The TTS engine **support speaking English, French, German, Italian and Spanish**, so I want to know:

Does this TTS engine also support Chinese speaking? 
If not, is there any other way to add this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Android TTS engine does not yet support Chinese.